# Python hard drive error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I have a problem I want Python search my all hard drive.There is sifreler.txt in D:\ but Python say print("File Not Found") why ?

```
hard_drive = 'D:\sifreler.txt' , 'E:\sifreler.txt' , 'F:\sifreler.txt' , 'G:\sifreler.txt' , 'H:\sifreler.txt' , 'I:\sifreler.txt'
hard_drive1 = hard_drive

while True:
    try:
        for i in hard_drive1:
            sifre = open(i, "r")
            sifree = sifre.readline()

        if sifree == "8da0dd52e2ee6c04528ede0cd84e6770":
            print("True")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: why have you tagged all Python tags? just tag only the Python version you are using.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal okey boss

Comment: import logging, then add 'logging.exception('')' to your except statement, try it and the provide the output

Comment: how I can use import logging

Comment: You need to prefix strings with literal backslash characters in them (like Windows paths) with an `r` character, like this: `hard_drive = r'D:\sifreler.txt', r'E:\sifreler.txt', etc...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 2 slashes. For instance: `X:\\` instead of `X:\`

*UPDATE*:

Also, change the `try/except` position. If some file does not exist, it will not kill the `for` block:

```
while True:
   for i in hard_drive1:
      try:
          sifre = open(i, "r")
          sifree = sifre.readline()

          if sifree == "8da0dd52e2ee6c04528ede0cd84e6770":
              print("True")

      except FileNotFoundError:
          print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: `hard_drive = 'D:\\sifreler.txt' , 'E:\\sifreler.txt' , 'F:\\sifreler.txt' , 'G:\\sifreler.txt' , 'H:\\sifreler.txt' , 'I:\\sifreler.txt'` dont work @manoelhc

Comment: Are you still getting "File Not Found"?

Comment: If you're still getting, probably one or more files might not exist, and you get this message. Perhaps you need to change your code a little bit.

Comment: yes File Not found There is a txt. no more how I change code  help me

Comment: Python Output `File Not Found
True
File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found`

Comment: As we can see, #1 file does not exist, #2 exists, and the rest don't exist. Right?